# Apache2 installation failed

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

Hi i am trying to install Apache2 server on my Ubuntu 12.04, but when i enter this command sudo apt-get install apache2 i am getting this error -

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+5) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

How do i fix this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I found answer while installing add apache2-bin dependency to do that follow this command :-
    sudo apt-get install install apache2 apache2-bin